# R: Creating a bar plot for each active feature in dataframe , grouped by class

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of this form:

```
df <- tibble(class = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), f1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), f2 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1))
  class    f1    f2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0
2     1     1     0
3     0     1     0
4     1     0     1
5     1     0     1
6     0     0     1
7     0     0     1
```

A now want to create a bar plot for each of the feature columns `f1` and `f2` in the following way. The bar plot should show the distribution over class (`0 or 1`) where a `feature == 1` (feature == 0 does not need to be considered). In words i want to know: is there a big class difference if a feature is active, i.e. `1`.

What is a nice way to achieve this  with ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-class, names_to = 'feature') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(feature, value, fill = factor(class))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'summary', fun = 'sum', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pimped alternative to @Axeman correct version!

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-class) %>% 
  group_by(class, name) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(name), y = sum, fill=factor(class))) +
  geom_col(position=position_stack(), width= 0.6)+
  labs(x="Feature", y="Value", fill="class") +
  geom_text(aes(label =  sum),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), color="white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]